# Сборка сайта на React JS - на Gulp делать верстку, а на WebPack - собирать приложение?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, gulp

Я хочу написать простой лендинг, а потом делать его на React JS. Объясните, пожалуйста, правильный ли такой ход действий:

1. Сверстать сайт в сборщике Gulp4(папка layout)
2. Создать папку(допустим project) в которую установлю React и WebPack
3. Работать в папке project, таская туда компоненты из папки layout.

Как это делают профессионалы?

Comment: а что именно будет собирать gulp? Если реакт ты будешь добавлять позже

Comment: По сути Gulp соберет мне папку с приложением, которая и не будет нужна для работы с React, так как там нужны отдельные компоненты. Получается надо верстать сразу в WebPack? Как это делают профи?

Comment: То есть ты хочешь дважды проделывать одну и ту же работу? Сначала в gulp потом в реакте?

Comment: По ходу да)) Тогда так: верстаю в WebPack, потом устанавливаю React. Да, это был тупой вопрос.

Comment: веб пак и так в реакте используется

Comment: Тогда получается верстать можно сразу в реакте?

Comment: Можно, почему нельзя?